# Custom datatable output

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I am quite new to windows forms(.net 3.5) and are trying to present some bound data in a good way.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
date        -      unit     -      message
2012-01-01         200             some text
2012-01-01         300             some text
2012-01-01         400             some text
2012-01-02         100             some text
2012-01-02         300             some text
2012-01-02         700             some text
```

I would like to output this to:

```
units       -    2012-01-01 - 2012-01-02   - count
200              some text                   1
100                           some text      1
300              some text    some text      2
```

and so on...is this possible? And where should I start? I not aware of all functions and controls available and maybe you guys have some clever ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
public DataTable ReadExcel()
{
        String excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=test.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";
        OleDbConnection excelCon = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
        OleDbCommand excelSelectCmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [stock$]", excelCon);
        OleDbDataAdapter excelAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        excelAdapter.SelectCommand = excelSelectCmd;
        DataSet excelDS = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        excelAdapter.Fill(excelDS);
        excelCon.Close();

         return dt;
}
```

So basically i am only populating a datatable from an excel file and returning it, then i am binding it to a DataGridView, the data is shown as expected in the grid.

Now I am just looking for a way to present the data in another way.

```
        DBLayer test = new DBLayer();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = test.ReadExcel();
```

Comment: You have to group by `unit` only or by `message` also?

Comment: This is a very broad question touching on several different areas of development. I would recommend narrowing your question to specific technical area.

Comment: It looks like you want to add a new column for each distinct date in the Date column. I'd recommend against this as a single years worth of data would have 365 columns.

Comment: Michael, yes, I will add a restriction mechanism to it(max 20 days maybe). It should'nt be necessary to have a lot of dates in the excel source file I am using for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope it will help.

**EDIT5** I have added the binding to dataGridView

```
public static class GroupedDtoWorker
{
    public static List<GroupedDto> GetIt()
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Columns.Add("date").DataType = typeof(DateTime);
        dataTable.Columns.Add("unit").DataType = typeof(Int32);
        dataTable.Columns.Add("message").DataType = typeof(String);
        dataTable.Rows.Add("27.5.1989", "200", "someText");
        dataTable.Rows.Add("27.6.1989", "300", "someText");
        dataTable.Rows.Add("27.7.1989", "400", "someText");
        dataTable.Rows.Add("27.8.1989", "100", "someText");
        dataTable.Rows.Add("27.9.1989", "300", "someText");
        dataTable.Rows.Add("27.10.1989", "700", "someText");

        var result = (from rows in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                      select new Dto
                      {
                          DateTime = rows.Field<DateTime>("date"),
                          Unit = rows.Field<Int32>("unit"),
                          Message = rows.Field<String>("message")

                      }).GroupBy(e => e.Unit)
                            .Select(
                                e =>
                                new GroupedDto()
                                {
                                    DateMessage = GetDictionary(e),
                                    Unit = e.AsQueryable().First().Unit,
                                    Count = e.Count()
                                }).ToList();
        return result;
    }

    public static Dictionary<String, String> GetDictionary(IGrouping<int, Dto> input)
    {
        Dictionary<String, String> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        input.ToList().ForEach(e => result.Add(e.DateTime.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), e.Message));
        return result;
    }

}

public class GroupedDto
{
    public Int32 Unit { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<String, String> DateMessage { get; set; }
    public Int32 Count { get; set; }
}

public class Dto
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public Int32 Unit { get; set; }
    public String Message { get; set; }
}
```

And the DataGridView bindings:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var dto = GroupedDtoWorker.GetIt();
        dataGridView.Columns.Add("units", "units");
        foreach (GroupedDto groupedDto in dto)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair in groupedDto.DateMessage)
            {
                if (!dataGridView.Columns.Contains(keyValuePair.Key))
                {
                    dataGridView.Columns.Add(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Key);
                }
            }
        }
        dataGridView.Columns.Add("count", "count");

        foreach (GroupedDto groupedDto in dto)
        {
            String[] row = new string[dataGridView.Columns.Count];
            row[0] = groupedDto.Unit.ToString();
            row[dataGridView.Columns.Count - 1] = groupedDto.Count.ToString();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair in groupedDto.DateMessage)
            {
                Int32 index = dataGridView.Columns[keyValuePair.Key].Index;
                row[index] = keyValuePair.Value;
            }
            dataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I will try this. However my table is a populated datatable(source is an excel-file)...can I use this approach against a populated datatable?

And the dates should be like columns

Comment: You can use Linq with datatable, so I think it should work. But, you have to delete `context.` and also replace `tableName` with your name  of exemplar of DataTable. Also you have to use .AsEnumerable()

Comment: Hm it says 
"Can not convert source type EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow> to target type Generic.List<Dto>

Comment: Maybe I can just create a new datatable and populate that with loops to get columns named as dates and so on...based on the first table

Comment: Haha no I know, I will try to do that to make sure I've got a working "plan b" :) Please let me know if you manage to figure out a better way

Comment: Look my way after **EDIT1**

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get the list...still having some problems to print it the way I want. Did you manage to print it the way I am looking for? (see my first post)

Comment: Yeap it's an interesting issue. Trying to solve it. Wait a bit

Comment: Sorry for a long waiting. I have renewed my answer, now it is working as you wrote in your question. Also I have used the `Derek` idea, so thx a lot to him.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Maris but I don't get the results I am looking for, sorry :/ I had to go for the non-sportsman-like way, it works but it's very ugly...

Comment: Why, in the result you get: DateMessage(Dictionary<String, String> key-date, value-Message), unit, count. So you will just left to bind it to grid.

Comment: Wow! It worked great! Sorry for that. It was the binding part that I did'nt do correct. Thanks a lot Maris!

Comment: Strange, when I try to add my own data everything works but it still adds all the columns as empty columns. So it shows 94 columns, one column for every date in the file but 90 of them are empty because everything are grouped in the first 4...

Comment: Oh, my bad. I forgot to add one If() in griw view binding... Renewed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to query a Datatable with LINQ then you will be best doing the Following :-

```
public class Dto
{
    public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }
    public Int32 Unit { get; set; }
    public String Message { get; set; }
}


public List<Dto> GetEnumerableObject()
{

       //Populate your Datatable from Excel Spreadsheet here as your already doing


       Var Result = (from rows in DataTable.AsEnumerable()

                     select new Dto
                     {
                        dateTime = rows.Field<DateTime>("date"),
                        Unit = rows.Field<Int32>("unit"),
                        Message = rows.Field<string>("message")

                     }).ToList();

       return Result;

}
```

In your maincode  you can do something like this :-

```
List<Dto> myList = GetEnumerableObject();
```

Then you can learn the pleasures of LINQ.

Comment: Thanks! I will try...can I use "myList" as a datasource for the grid?

Comment: Yes you can, its an enumerable object.